# favorite icon color is green

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm developing a flutter shop app. My issue looks simple, however I'm stuck and cannot find a solution for it.
I have a favorite icon for each product in a grid view, I configured the accent color of the theme in the main class, and then set the color for the icon in product item class. However, the favorite icon color is showing in green not in the accent color I've configured.

main class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/providers/products.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/screens/product_details_screen.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/screens/products_overview_screen.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => Products(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'MyShop',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
          fontFamily: 'Lato',
        ),
        home: ProductsOverviewScreen(),
        routes: {
          ProductDetailsScreen.routeName: (context) => ProductDetailsScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the product item class where this icon is configured:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/providers/product.dart';
import 'package:shopping_app/screens/product_details_screen.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context, listen: false);
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: GridTile(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
              ProductDetailsScreen.routeName,
              arguments: product.id,
            );
          },
          child: Image.network(
            product.imageURL,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        footer: GridTileBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
          leading: Consumer<Product>(
            builder: (context, product, _) => IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                product.isFavoriate ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
              ),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, //here is where I set the accent color
              onPressed: () {
                product.toggleFavoriateStatus();
              },
            ),
          ),
          
         
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my toggle function:

```
void toggleFavoriateStatus() {
    isFavoriate = !isFavoriate;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Comment: Where is your togglefavouriteStatus() function? There might be some issue with that function. Please share it. Also, I'm able to display the exact color which I wanted and my color thing is working properly but I have removed the provider package.

Comment: I added it, please check

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think the problem is that you are setting the color to IconButton instead of Icon. try this

```
 Icon(
        product.isFavoriate ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
        color: Theme.of(context).accentColor, //here is where I set the accent color
      ),
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Even after that, it works.

Comment: it has sense. You need to set the icon color not the button color. Anyway i'm happy now it's work. Have a good day and happy coding

Comment: Either you use it inside an Icon or Icon Button it will be the same, until you have other different plans

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me. Maybe this can help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyShop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
        accentColor: Colors.pink,
        fontFamily: 'Lato',
      ),
      home: ProductItem(),
    );
  }
}

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
          ),
          color: Theme.of(context)
              .accentColor, //here is where I set the accent color
          onPressed: () {
            print("hello");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;`

Also, you may set the color value for the Icon itself but it is not necessary.

```
IconButton(
         icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,),
         color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        ),
```